# How to change id name with a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code in question:

```
function incepeSlider(){
numaratoare = $('.sectiune_chic').size();
loop = setInterval (function(){
        if(slideSecund > numaratoare){
            slideSecund = 1;
            slidePrim = 1;
            }
        $('.sectiune_chic').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#chic' + slideSecund).fadeIn(1000);
        slidePrim = slideSecund
        slideSecund = slideSecund + 1;
    },6000)}
```

The goal is to create a function that replaces the word chic with funky in the entire script so that the script runs but on other ids. I want to create buttons that when clicked would replace the script above with:

```
function incepeSlider(){
numaratoare = $('.sectiune_funky').size();
loop = setInterval (function(){
        if(slideSecund > numaratoare){
            slideSecund = 1;
            slidePrim = 1;
            }
        $('.sectiune_funky').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#funky' + slideSecund).fadeIn(1000);
        slidePrim = slideSecund
        slideSecund = slideSecund + 1;
    },6000)
```

}

these are some examples of what I tried:

```
function activeazaFunky(){
$('chic').replaceWith('funky');}
```

,

```
function activeazaFunky(){
chic = funky;}
```

Comment: I really recommend to read the documentation before you try out certain functions: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a function, why not make the part that is variable, the ID, a parameter of the function?

```
function incepeSlider(id){
    numaratoare = $('.sectiune_' + id).size();
    loop = setInterval (function(){
        if(slideSecund > numaratoare){
            slideSecund = 1;
            slidePrim = 1;
        }
        $('.sectiune_' + id).fadeOut(1000);
        $('#' + id + slideSecund).fadeIn(1000);
        slidePrim = slideSecund
        slideSecund = slideSecund + 1;
    },6000)
}
```

to be called as

```
incepeSlider('chic');
// or
incepeSlider('funky');
```

You should probably also make those variables inside the function local (use the `var` keyword).

Comment: Should also probably not be using `"strings"+nums` for classes and IDs.

Comment: Thank you. passing the new parameter through the function was creating some issues so I went with `function activeazaFunky(){stil = 'funky'}` and it works exactly as it should. Thanks again.